# SonataPageBundle remove page composer

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I install and full configurate sonata page bundle. But there is on edit/add page page composer. There is the way to remove page composer from sonata page admin area?

Comment: There is no simple way on how to deactivate the compose-feature in SonataPageBundle. You'll need to override the ```Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin``` and remove (or deny access to) compose feature.

Comment: ok so I have to overwrite configureSideMenu method?

Comment: Yes, but your users will still get access to compose if they know and type the URL directly. So I would suggest deleting them in ```configureRoutes()``` too.